# I am unable to install apc on windows wampserver

Tags: apache, windows-7, apc, wampserver

I am unable to install apc on wampserver windows 7.

downloaded from  http://downloads.php.net/pierre/

Copy php_apc.dll to \wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\ext

this is my php.ini configuration

```
[APC]
apc.enabled = 1
apc.shm_segments = 1
apc.shm_size = 64M
apc.max_file_size = 10M
apc.stat = 1

extensions=php_apc.dll
```

and then restart wampserver

Open this address `http://localhost/?phpinfo=1` in browser

but still unable to find apc section because if apc is installed successfully on wampserver then it must show in phpinfo with new section for apc but it not showing any apc setting or apc section. please help me

Comment: YOur question is not making sense clearly...please make your quesion more clear that what you wanna do exactly and which type of problem you are facing exactly..however please see this link may be it can help you.
http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php

Comment: i means i want to install apc extension on my wampserver by phpinfo of wampserver it not showing installed apc

Comment: Read the tutorial [How to install APC on Wamp](http://blog.lardev.com/2011/07/06/install-apc-on-wamp-server/). It seems you didnt add extention line in `php.ini`